# How to give conditional statements within Pandas' pivot_table function?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate

This code is working but not the way I wanted:

```
vor_merged_to_dad_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    vor_merged_to_dad,
    index=['ID'], 
    values=['MDD_Y', 'ADMITDATE'],
    aggfunc={
        'MDD_Y':np.sum,
        'ADMITDATE':np.min
    }
)
```

I want to get the minimal ADMITDATE but only when MDD_Y is equal to one, I tried this but doesn't work:

```
vor_merged_to_dad_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    vor_merged_to_dad,
    index=['ID'], 
    values=['MDD_Y', 'ADMITDATE'],
    aggfunc={
        'MDD_Y':np.sum,
        'ADMITDATE':np.min if 'MDD_Y'==1
    }
) 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this problem is to add a helper column:

```
max_value = vor_merged_to_dad['ADMITDATE'].max()

vor_merged_to_dad['ADMITDATE2'] = np.where(vor_merged_to_dad['MDD_Y_DAD'] == 1,
                                           vor_merged_to_dad['ADMITDATE'], max_value)
```

Then use 'ADMITDATE2' in your `groupby` aggregation.

Comment: I think I see your general direction of your logic. I can create a new column ['ADMITDATE2'] with ['ADMITDATE'] duplicated if ['MDD_Y_DAD'] == 1, then just find the np.min of ['ADMITDATE2']. Your code isn't doing that. I will accept your answer if no one is giving a one line solution that implements the conditional statement within the aggfunc. Thanks.